# Possible memory leak in multiple asynchronous invocations of JS callbacks

Tags: memory-leaks, callback, firebreath

Under certain circumstances, we have to make hundred of thousands asynchronous invocations of a JS callback in our plugin, ie. FB::JSObject::InvokeAsync().
We noticed that the memory usage of our plugin, which runs in a separate process in Firefox or Chrome, keeps rising even though we don't keep any memory references to the data we send (the JS callback receives just an integer parameter).
We used valgrind to track down the place of the memory leaks and if we are interpreting the log output correctly, it seems that the source of the leaks comes from the entry to the function FB::JSObject::InvokeAsync().
Any known issues related to Firebreath memory leaks in multiple asynchronous invocations of JS callbacks and how we can fix it?

Comment: no known issues, but that doesn't mean there aren't any.  you fix it by identifying what is leaking and then changing the code so that it doesn't leak.

Comment: We used valgrind to debug the possible memory leak that may come from multiple asynchronous invocations of JS callbacks.
We build a simple test where we invoke asynchronously a single callback multiple times in a loop.
From the valgrind's log it seems that the most important leak comes from the line "CrossThreadCall *call = new CrossThreadCall(funct);" located in the method: void CrossThreadCall::asyncCall(const FB::BrowserHostConstPtr &host, const boost::shared_ptr<C>& obj, Functor func) (src/ScriptingCore/CrossThreadCall.h)

Comment: Looks like the memory used in this function for variable call is never released. 
Another important leak, which has half size from the previous one, comes from line 1 of the same function, but we couldn't find out why.
Unfortunately, the specific part of Firebreath's code is too complex to analyse since we are not familiar with the project. Any help to fix it would be welcome. 
Please see valgrind's output here:https://gist.github.com/ehostunreach/1dcc34d3bbe2b4d1dc32

Comment: Drop into IRC (web address http://npapi.com/chat) and I'll see if I can point you in the right direction

Comment: I dropped into IRC various time but I suppose that due to time difference I have not been able to chat with you. Is it possible to give us some guidelines here?

Comment: I'm GMT-0600, but I have been out a lot.  I'll be on most of this next week; you could also start a conversation on the firebreath-dev google group.

Comment: I am GMT +3:00. We have opened a jira issue long time ago. Please see the link: http://jira.firebreath.org/browse/FIREBREATH-258